# Alfresco Community 5.0 unable to upload files >5mb in size within share

Tags: windows, iis, file-upload, server, alfresco

So, I have Alfresco 5 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 and I am not able to upload documents that are larger than 5mb in size. Files smaller are uploading as expected.

Upon uploading a document >5mb in size an errors on the share site will pop up either being a 404 or 502. Nothing is being notated within the log files. Any ideas? I'm assuming it has to be a setting restricting file size limit, but I am unsure.

Comment: What happens if you try your upload skipping out IIS, and talking straight to Tomcat (eg port 8080)?

Comment: Have a look in `share-config-custom` for `<in-memory-limit>` and `<maximum-file-size-limit>` parameters.

Comment: When I go directly through tomcat locally, it is able to upload any size of files. So, this means it has to do with some sort of IIS setting or how IIS interacts with Tomcat. I would have used Apache to deploy this, but unfortunately I didn't get to choose. Also I did look in the share config and I have neither of those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution by changing web.config.

I added:

```
httpRuntime 
executionTimeout="90" 
maxRequestLength="10485760" 
useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
minFreeThreads="8" 
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
appRequestQueueLimit="100" 
enableVersionHeader="true"
```

I'm not sure this is best practice, but thus is life trying to use Microsoft products with software developed for Apache.